# ManyToManyField not saving correctly

Tags: django, postgresql

I have an `item_option` this is a `ManyToManyFiled` that links to an `ItemOption` model.

In the Django panel, I can insert `ItemOptions`, and they are saved correctly in the database, but `product.item_option.all()` returns an empty array.

I found that the `ItemOption` is being inserted but nothing is being inserted in the ManyToManyTable `database_product_item_option`.

Manually adding the indexes to this table fixes the problem, and I can successfully retrieve ItemOptions using `product.item_option.all()`

How can I make Django do this automatically? I feel like I'm close to the solution but I haven't been able to find what's wrong with my code or what's missing.

Here's my code:

Product

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...
    item_option = models.ManyToManyField('ItemOption', blank=True, related_name='item_option')
```

ItemOption

```py
class ItemOption(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Form

```py
class ItemOptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemOption
        fields = ['name', 'price', 'default']


class ItemOptionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ItemOption
    form = ItemOptionForm
    extra = 1
    can_delete = True

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'price', 'product_type')
    list_filter = ('product_type', 'brand')
    exclude = ('item_option',)
    inlines = [ItemOptionInline]


admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

Comment: You have two links, a `ForeignKey` and a `ManyToManyField`, likely that makes not much sense. Often there is *either* a FK from one model to another, or an m2m in between.

Comment: At first sight it looks like an option is specific to a *single* product (since it has for example a price attached to it), so in that case the m2m makes not much sense, and the fk should be retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two links, a `ForeignKey` and a `ManyToManyField`, likely that makes not much sense. While not fundamentally impossible, often there is *either* a `ForeignKey` from one model to another, or an `ManyToManyField` in between. The `ModelAdmin` here picked the `product` foreign key, since that is the only thing, an `InlineModelAdmin` can use "out of the box".

This is not trivial if you want to use a `ManyToManyField`. But if you define a `ManyToManyField`, you create a (hidden) model. Indeed, one with two `ForeignKey`s: in this case one that points to a `Product` and one to an `ItemOption`. So we can work with that model as is specified in the [*working with many-to-many models* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models):

```
class ItemOptionThroughInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Product.item_option.through
    extra = 1
    can_delete = True


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'price', 'product_type')
    list_filter = ('product_type', 'brand')
    exclude = ('item_option',)
    inlines = [ItemOptionThroughInline]
```

this will however only make pointing to already existing `ItemOption`s convenient. It would also be weird to have an `ItemOption` form anyway: it means that if you change an `ItemOption` that is linked on two `Product`s, through the edit page of one product, then the change is thus also reflected in the edit page of the other product. So likely, you simply wanted a `ForeignKey` in the `ItemOption` model, and make options, specific to a (single) `Product`.

Comment: I did try with `Product.item_option.through` before, but it was giving me errors related to the fields and nothing was showing up in the Django panel, I tried again and it worked! just had to reset the database to clear a few errors that were showing in the panel, but it works now, THANKS!